# Can we define Mobius function for any real number and any complex number ?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

All:

To me, Mobius function is a bit mysterious. I just want to know if we can define 
Mobius function for any real number or any complex number ?

Can anyone point out any resource on this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to the $\mu$ function that is equal to $\pm1$ at square-free numbers and $0$ at other numbers? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I suppose you could define it for rational $r/s$ by $\mu(r/s)=\mu(r)\mu(s)$. Beyond that, well, what properties would you want it to have? That's the question to answer, before you try to define it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by defining it for any real or complex number.

But (assuming that by Möbius function you mean the standard thing whose value at square-free numbers is $\pm1$ depending on whether the number of prime factors is even or odd, and equal to $0$ elsewhere) there is a thing called an [incidence algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra).

Every locally finite partially ordered set has an incidence algebra, in which the identity element for multiplication is called the $\delta$ function, the function everywhere equal to $1$ is the $\zeta$ function, and the inverse of the $\zeta$ function is the $\mu$ function.  In the special case in which the poset is the positive integers ordered by divisibility, the $\mu$ function is the standard $\mu$ function mentioned in the paragraph above.

**PS:** I just realized that what you meant was: "Can one define $\mu(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ or $x\in\mathbb C$?".  I would guess not in any reasonable way.